# Determine Number of Elements in a FloatBuffer

Tags: java, floatbuffer

`FloatBuffer` has the method `capacity()` which tells us the maximum capacity of the `FloatBuffer`. However, it does not tell us how many elements are in that buffer. So how can I determine the number of elements in a `FloatBuffer`? I am trying to determine if my `FloatBuffer` is full or partially full.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can never keep the NIO buffer's straight in my head, but [`remaining()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#remaining%28%29) might be what you're after...

> Returns the number of elements between the current position and the limit.

(Or just use [`hasRemaining()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#hasRemaining%28%29) if you're after a simple Boolean...)

Comment: I'm getting `0` for remaining() so I must be doing something wrong. I know there is data in there.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Have you called `flip()` after writing? Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Flip was it. Thanks. Called flip() after put() then checked remaining().

Comment: Depending on what you're doing `flip()` may not be what you're after, since it resets the limit to the current position. You should look at `rewind`, though without further information everything's possible (maybe it's just `limit()` or even `position()`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  As with an array of floats you can get the length but which ones have been set is determined by the application.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I determine the number of elements in a FloatBuffer?

Wouldn't it just be the position() ?

To determine if you can write more to it, just test for fb.remaining() > 0 or fb.hasRemaining().

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purpose just use

> floatBuffer.toString()

At the end of the string the informations about the current position and the capacity will be shown, like

> ...[pos=0 lim=1024 cap=1024]